# What is this glass bulb containing three parallel electrodes?

Tags: pcb, ac, identification, triac, vacuum-tube

I'm trying to figure out what the glass component on the PCB is. Maybe some sort of vacuum tube? Maybe a triac? It's got three leads, and appears to have three parallel electrodes inside the glass bulb.

This is from a 70s/80s heated blanket. One outer leg is connected directly to +120VAC, the other leg is connected to huge (inch-long) resistor that is in turn connected to the other -120VAC. The center leg connects to resistors that in turn connect to the heating elements of the heated blanket. The other end of those heating elements are directly connected to +V and -V.

Pictures of the front, back, and annotated PCB.

Long story short, this blanket used to pull 100W from the wall and now only pulls 25W. This is the only part of the blanket with any electronics so I'm curious what's worn out.

Any advice is welcome!

[image: front]

[image: back]

[image: annotated]

Comment: Looks like a neon lamp of some sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a gas breakdown tube, part of a safety circuit.

There are several patents showing this, such as:

[US Patent 44369886](https://patents.justia.com/patent/4436986) Electric blanket safety circuit.

[US Patent 5451747A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5451747A/en) Flexible self-regulating heating pad combination and associated method.

The first one uses two separate tubes, the second has a 3 wire tube as in your photo and is possibly what yours is based on.

As far as I understand it from a quick browse of the patents it appears that the circuit is balanced and if one leg of the heating coil open circuits the tube breaks down, drawing enough current to blow the fuse.

Comment: Thanks for this! So clearly not an off the shelf part. Really appreciate the leads on the patents, those are interesting reads.